# bigquery left join from constants

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I defined a query as constants and do a left join to a table?

I'm trying to do like this, but it's not workitng

```
#standardSQL
select 
"name" custom_campaign_defined,
"welcome" as funnel_step
from '1' data
left join table on table.campaign = data.custom_campaign_defined
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Why? What? Why?

Comment: I'm generating a column to left join with some tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a subquery.  It is something like this, although the referenced columns make it unclear what you exactly want:

```
select t."name" as custom_campaign_defined,
       t."welcome" as funnel_step
from (select '1' as custom_campaign_defined) d left join
     table t
     on t.campaign = d.custom_campaign_defined
```